# Unity SkinnedMeshRenderer bind to bones error

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBLvKR2E62Q&index=10&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0f4c56CbvYi038zmCmoZ4CQ)

Wanting to generate SkinnedMesh and bind to bones with Script

```c#
public SkinnedMeshRenderer shirtMesh;
public SkinnedMeshRenderer targetMesh;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    //SkinnedMeshRenderer sm = Instantiate(shirtPrefab).GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
    SkinnedMeshRenderer sm = Instantiate<SkinnedMeshRenderer>(shirtMesh);

    sm.transform.parent = targetMesh.transform.parent;
    sm.bones = targetMesh.bones;
    sm.rootBone = targetMesh.rootBone;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

As shown in the screen shot the blue mesh (shirt) is deformed incorrectly. (This mesh worked as expected if loaded in the editor when it gets imported)

Am I missing anythings?

Comment: What's the error? What's the question here?

Comment: Please add more information. For us to help you we will require what trouble you are facing. If you have log available of error please do post that also.

Comment: @SwiftingDuster The blue mesh is deformed in correctly, if bind in this way with script.